# Como crear un array de n posiciones, C++

Tags: c++, array, contenedores

Mi pregunta es como declarar un array sin especificar la longitud y luego el instanciarlo en el método constructor especificando la cantidad.

Para entrar en contexto, dejo el siguiente ejemplo.

```
#ifndef GRAFO_H
#define GRAFO_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class grafo {
public:
    grafo();
    grafo(const grafo& orig);
    virtual ~grafo();
private:
    int num_pla;
    string nom_pla[]; // Declaración sin especificar el tamaño del array.
};

#endif /* GRAFO_H */
```

Ahora lo que busco es instanciarlo en el constructor de la clase y especificarle la longitud tal como el siguiente ejemplo en JAVA.

```
String b[] = new String[9];
```

Ahora, ¿Esto es posible?, si no es así; ¿Que otra forma recomendarían, para solventar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Contestación a tu pregunta**

Cuando defines un array, el tamaño debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación, por lo que no puedes definirlo tal y como lo estás haciendo.

Sin embargo puedes definir un puntero a `string` y mas tarde en el constructor reservar la memoria dinámicamente, tal que así:

```
// En la clase
string *nom_pla;

// Mas tarde en el constructor
nom_pla = new string[x];
```

Recuerda hacer un `delete` en el destructor para liberar la memoria.

**Recomendaciones**

Sin embargo, te recomiendo que no utilices un array y/o los operadores new y delete, para construir colecciones que ya existen, a no ser que tengas claro y justificado el uso de los mismos.

Por ejemplo, podrías utilizar la clase `std::vector` para almacenar un array de `strings`.

```
// En la clase
std::vector<string> nom_pla;
```

Por último, también te aconsejo que elimines la línea:

```
using namespace std;
```

La comunidad está de acuerdo en considerarlo una mala práctica, debido a los conflictos que pudieran surgir en un futuro con las librerías estandard y de terceros.

Un saludo

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con tu respuesta, te agradezco por tu redacción, lo tomare en cuenta, te ganaste el check.